# Add some has invalid argument while inserting data Using Abstract Class

Tags: c#, model-view-controller

Here I'm having two tables in this two table I just take common columns as an abstract class when I try to insert some data into two tables why I'm getting error at `"db.Access1.Add(ass1)"`

This is my Base class Here I am just taking common columns:

```
namespace ImageWithallCtrls.Models
    {
    public abstract class BaseAccessClass
        {
            public string F_Name { get; set; }
            public string L_Name { get; set; }
        }
    }

    namespace ImageWithallCtrls.Models
    {
        public class AccessClass2 :BaseAccessClass
        {
            public string L_Name { get; set; }
            public string PersonName { get; set; }

        }
    }
    namespace ImageWithallCtrls.Models
    {
        public class AccessClass1 : BaseAccessClass
        {
            public string Middle_Name { get; set; }
            public string Gender { get; set; }
        }
    }
```

**Home.cs**

```
public ActionResult AbsAssClass(Genral Gen)
{
    AccessClass1 ass1 = new AccessClass1
     {

        F_Name = Gen.F_Name,
        L_Name = Gen.L_Name,
        Gender = Gen.Gender,
        Middle_Name = Gen.Middle_Name

    };

    AccessClass2 ass2 = new AccessClass2
    {
        F_Name = Gen.F_Name,
        L_Name = Gen.L_Name,
        PersonName = Gen.PersonName
    };
    db.Access1.Add(ass1);
```

Comment: *"im getting error at"* is not an error message... you must provide the error message in order to be helped

Comment: Error 3 The best overloaded method match for 'System.Data.Entity.DbSet<ImageWithallCtrls.Access1>.Add(ImageWithallCtrls.Access1)' has some invalid arguments G:\ItsLast\ImageWithallCtrls\ImageWithallCtrls\Controllers\HomeController.cs 92 13 ImageWithallCtrls